# Block an app from accessing the internet when a specific WiFi network is used

Tags: windows-10, firewall

I have a metered connection on WiFi network with a traffic limit. I want to stop Google Drive to sync my files when I'm connected to this network in order to stop spending limited gigabytes.

I only see that Windows Firewall can block an app depending on whether a network is domain, private or public, but I couldn't find if Windows Firewall could block an app if Windows uses a specific WiFi connection.

Is it possible to implement such scenario?

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: I'm not advocating it and I don't even use Windows, but it looks to me like you may need to change to Onedrive which appears to support this functionality - https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/117911-disable-sync-your-settings-metered-connections-windows-10-a.html - I could not find anything similar for Google Drive.

Comment: Alternatively if your primary connection is vi ethernet, you can, I believe, block Sync on WIFI connections, so it will only sync when connected to Ethernet.

Comment: @davidgo Changing to OneDrive is not a solution for me. A few years ago I investigated Google Drive, OneDrive and Dropbox and selected Google Drive for reasons not relevant to this topic.